# Host keeps going down running python TCP sockets

Tags: python, tcp, host, lan

I'm currently working on a Python utility for LAN's, and currently, if I run the program repeatedly, it will intermittently throw this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netbin.py", line 49, in <module>
    results = pool.map(ping, pAddress)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 522, in get
    raise self._value
socket.error: [Errno 64] Host is down
```

Is there a reason that this issue might keep coming up?

Comment: It seems that the machine is unreachable for some reason. Try making ping to the machine's ip

Comment: as in my own IP? I've pinged it and it responds in ~.1 ms.

Comment: it also sometimes throws [Errno 65] No route to host

Comment: Since we do not see your code we can speculate what the reason is. Also, please, provide information about the operating system.

Comment: We're using two Mac OS X's. We basically ended up solving it by just disconnecting and reconnecting to wi-fi every time it happens.